# Creating a XUL button gives "component failure code"

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm one of the developers of TryAgain, a Firefox add-on, that displays a custom error page when a website fails to load. It essentially replaces Firefox's `netError.xhtml` with a customized version.

In order to execute JavaScript from the extension code within the `netError.xhtml`, I've added a XUL `<command>` element to the error page as follows:

```
var increment_btn = doc.
    createElementNS(
        "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul",
        "xul:command"
    );
increment_btn.setAttribute("id", "errorIncrement");
increment_btn.setAttribute("oncommand", "autoRetryThis();");
div.appendChild(increment_btn);
```

Whenever `autoRetryThis()` needs to be executed, I simply run `doCommand()` on the element. On my testing machine, this works fine under Firefox 2.0 through 4.0b10. I've received [the following problem report](http://getsatisfaction.com/tryagain/topics/tryagain_error?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=new_topic), however:

> Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.createElementNS]

The error points to the first line of the above code.

If you're wondering why I chose to create the element using `createElementNS()`, please [refer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698950/xul-button-doesnt-appear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the XUL namespace has been deprecated. To my understanding, this means that it is no longer possible to place XUL and XHTML controls within a single XML document.

My solution was to instead use a normal XHTML `<button>` tag, and call it's `onclick()` listener by dispatching the event:

```
try {
    var evt = doc.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('click', false, false);
    btn.dispatchEvent(evt);
} catch (e) {
    btn.click();
}
```

Why not just do `btn.click()` in the first place? I discovered some incompatibilities between using this method and add-ons that monitored clicking on the document. Dispatching the event directly circumvents this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `xul:` from the name parameter of `createElementNS`.

Comment: I'll try this and submit a revised version, but it will have to go through the timely editorial process. Can you elaborate on why this is causing a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to fix the issue however.  Remote XUL was disabled in Firefox 4.0, and I suspect that is what is being hit here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546857

Comment: I think you're right. The bug report references another, where [this message](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623482#c0) specifically states: "Currently if someone tries to create a XUL element we simply fail the action
and throw an error." The strange thing is: it works on one machine and not on another. What gives?